# Remotely accesing ftp server on pc

Tags: ftp, ftp-client, ftp-server

My problem is the following I want to develop and app that downloads some files in a ftp server(my laptop) which I could easily solve if I were on the same lan.

What can I do to connect by ftp to my laptop when the phone is connected to a different lan than the computer?

Can be this problem solved by setting my router to port forward? How can I do this?

I have tried setting an account in no-ip.biz but I must wait 60 days to activate my domain and I when I ping my host I get responded like if it was online. But I can't access it through the web browser, ssh or telnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a port forward on your router. Use port 21 and redirect it to your laptop.

Then to access it from everywhere connect to your box IP.